# Connection string property has not been initialized SqlCommandBuilder

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, winforms, datagridview

I try to update my database from a Windows Forms applicatoin. The information shows in datagridview. When I click the update button, I get an exception :

> Connection string property has not been initialized

and

```
cmdBuilder.DataAdapter.UpdateCommand = null
```

My code:

```
public static string connectionString = @"Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Clothing_DB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
public void setNewSizes()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                adapterSize.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand(); //error here
                adapterSize.Update(recivedData.Tables[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
            }
    }
}
```

Нow can I fix it ?

Comment: from your source code it is not clear if you pass or not a connection reference to the Connection property of your Command object

Comment: Why are you creating a connection object and never using it?

Comment: @john  use in : try
            {
                conn.Open();

Comment: OK. I'll rephrase. Why are you creating a connection object and opening a connection to the database only to not use it and then dispose of it? It seems rather pointless and wasteful.

Comment: @john what do you mean ?

Comment: You open a connection that's scoped to the using(..) { } and then you never assign it to anything. It's never used. The only code that references it is conn.Open(); and that's it. It's never used.

Comment: @john adapterSize.Update(recivedData.Tables[0]); use the connection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141971/discussion-between-john-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not dispose the `SqlConnection` object you have created during `SqlDataAdapter` creation. You should not use new connection and there is no need to open and close it, the `SqlDataAdapter.Update(yourTable)` will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Find all references" for the **connectionString** property to find it's initialization.
Check your project, connection string values usually stored in the App.config or in the project Properties. Or hardcoded.